# how to setup jstree with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jstree

I am trying to build a tree view and found that jstree is nice to create tree. i have my rails application from where i can create the tree. i put jstree files in app/assets/javascript directory. following _lib directory and jquery.jstree.js. But i dont know where should i put themes directory.

app/assets/javascript

```
 _lib
 jquery.jstree.js
```

though i know that i can setup jquery.jstree.js in my app's asset pipelines javascript folder.
i just want to use the static html plugin of jstree where the list data will be changed dynamically

In my view files my list is as follows

```
<div id="selector">
   <ul>
 <li><a>JBP PROD</a>
    <ul>
        <% i = 0 %>
        <% while i< @params_jbp_prod.length %>
        <li><%= @params_jbp_prod[i] %> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp@
                    <i><%= @cl_jbp_prod[i] %> </i></li>
        <% i+=1 %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li><a>JBP SUKANTA</a>
    <ul>
        <% i = 0 %>
        <% while i< @params_jbp_main.length %>
        <li><%= @params_jbp_main[i] %> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp@
                    <i><%= @cl_jbp_main[i] %></i></li>
        <% i+=1 %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.jstree.js` follows its own folder structure. Irrespective of what scripting language you're using, put all the contents of jstree under one directory. In your case `app/assets/javascript/jstree`.

```
 + app
   + assets
     + javascript
       + jstree
         + themes
           + default
           |__ style.css
       |__ jquery.jstree.js
       |__ jquery.jstree.min.js
```

NOTE: The above is just a gist of how the folder structure should look like. There are other resources apart from themes directory

Make sure you initialize `jstree` using `jQuery`. In the same view file(which is shown above), include these lines.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
     jQuery("#selector").jstree({ 
        "themes" : {
            "theme" : "default",    
            "icons" : false
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data"]
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: should i include those jstree as they are external files in my view file or it will be added automatically ?

Comment: I haven't tried rails4. But in earlier versions of rails you have to include `.js` files in the layout of the corresponding views directory. Try viewing the page source(`ctrl-u`) if `jquery.jstree.js` is included or not

Comment: jquery.jstree.js and ja files from _lib is loaded by default but still can't build tree

Comment: Thanks i did those and getting the tree but only the italic block not the list block of my data .how to correct that.

Comment: I suppose this has to do something with your `ruby` code, can you hard code your `html` view and then try if the tree works? Use this html: `<div id="selector">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>JBP PROD</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       1
       <i>
        1 italics
       </i>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li> 
    <li>
     <a>JBP SUKANTA</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       2
       <i>
        2 italics
       </i>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>`

Comment: this html is working fine even my ruby code is working fine when it is not in tree. but while making tree <%= @params_jbp_main[i] %> is showing nothing. only <i><%= @cl_jbp_main[i] %></i> is showing value . i am not getting any clue.where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: when i placed <a></a> inside last child of list as like <li><a href="#">list</a></li> it worked :)